# Codeigniter and preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, preg-replace

I use Codeigniter to create a multilingual website and everything works fine, but when I try to use the "alternative languages helper" by Luis I've got a problem. This helper uses a regular expression to replace the current language with the new one:

```
$new_uri = preg_replace('/^'.$actual_lang.'/', $lang, $uri);
```

The problem is that I have a URL like this: `http://www.example.com/en/language/english/` and I want to replace only the first "**en**" without changing the word "**english**". I tried to use the limit for `preg_replace`:

```
$new_uri = preg_replace('/^'.$actual_lang.'/', $lang, $uri, 1);
```

but this doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$regex = '#^'.preg_quote($actual_lang, '#').'(?=/|$)#';
$new_uri = preg_replace($regex, $lang, $uri);
```

The last capture pattern basically means "only match if the next character is a forward slash or the end of the string"...

**Edit:**

If the code you always want to replace is at the beginning of the path, you could always do:

```
if (stripos($url, $actual_lang) !== false) {
    if (strpos($url, '://') !== false) {
        $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    } else {
        $path = $url;
    }
    list($language, $rest) = explode('/', $path, 2);
    if ($language == $actual_lang) {
        $url = str_replace($path, $lang . '/' . $rest, $url);
    }
}
```

It's a bit more code, but it should be fairly robust.  You could always build a class to do this for you (by parsing, replacing and then rebuilding the URL)...

Comment: The URL given in the question will still be matched by that regex.

Comment: It would still be matched, but only the first `en` part.  The trailing `english/` would not be matched (and hence would not be replaced)...

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. The URL won't be matched at all, because the URL doesn't start with en. Without the `^` anchor, however, `http://www.example.com/en/language/en/` would match twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the beginning of the URL will always, be, use it in the regex!

```
$domain = "http://www.example.com/"
$regex = '#(?<=^' . preg_quote($domain, '#') . ')' . preg_quote($actual_lang, '#') . '\b#';
$new_uri = preg_replace($regex, $lang, $uri);
```

In the case of your example, the regular expression would become `#(?<=^http://www.example.com/)en\b` which would match `en` only if it followed the specified beginning of a domain (`(?<=...)` in a regular expression specifies a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) and is followed by a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (so `english` wouldn't match).